# insert method for an array of objects c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, memory-management, insert

I have an array of integer data called values and I need to insert a new Integerdata into the array. I have thought about making a temp array to copy all the contents and then make a new array with a size + 1 the original but I keep getting many errors. any help?

```
class IntegerData : public Data {
public:
int value;

// This is the syntax for a constructor that initializes the
// properties value to the parameters
IntegerData(int value) : value(value) {}

}
class ArrayCollection : Collection {
// length of values is always the same as count
Data ** values;
int count;

public:
ArrayCollection() {
  // initialize the array to NULL
  this->values = NULL;
  this->count = 0;
}

~ArrayCollection() {
  // must clean up the internally allocated array here
  if (values != NULL) {
    delete [] values;
  }
}

/**
 * Returns the count of the number of elements in the Collection
 */
int size() const {
  return count;
}



  /**
 * Gets the Data value at the specified index.  If index >= size() then
 * NULL is returned.
 */
Data * get(int index) {
  if (index >= size()) {
    return NULL;
  }
  else {
    return values[index];
  }
}



????-- I need help with this method--
 // I try to dynamically allocate tempArray but I get the error message saying: cannot
 // allocate an object of abstract type 'Data'
void insert(Data * other){
count++;
Data **tempArray = new Data[count];

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

tempArray[i] = values[i];
}

delete [] values;



  values = tempArray;

}




}






int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
// create an ArrayCollection for our collection of integers
ArrayCollection * collection = new ArrayCollection();

if (argc == 1) {
// they didn't provide any arguments to the program, insert a
// value of zero so that the main function still works
collection->insert(new IntegerData(0));
}
else {
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
  // read user input for integer value
  int x = atoi(argv[i]);

  // insert it to our collection
  collection->insert(new IntegerData(x));
 }
}

// print the collection
cout << collection->toString() << endl;

// check the implementation of member
IntegerData * five = new IntegerData(5);
cout << "five is a member of collection? " << collection->member(five) << endl;

// now we are going to insert and remove a few items -- MARKER (a)
IntegerData * v0 = (IntegerData *)collection->get(0);
collection->remove(v0);
cout << collection->toString() << endl;

// check after removing the 0th element  -- MARKER (b)
cout << "five is a member of collection? " << collection->member(five) << endl;

collection->insert(v0);
cout << collection->toString() << endl;

// check after inserting the 0th element back
cout << "five is a member of collection? " << collection->member(five) << endl;

// clean up memory
delete five;

// must delete IntegerData instances that we allocated in main
// because they are not deleted by the data structure
for (int i = 0; i < collection->size(); i++) {
delete collection->get(i);
}
// now delete the data structure  -- MARKER (c)
delete collection;
}
```

Comment: Where is values getting initialized? Unless it's already at least of size count++, you're going to go out of range in your array when you try to insert.

Comment: Why don't you make your new array size 1 larger, and have your insert function take 2 arguments.  The 2 arguments would be the data to insert, and the index to insert it at.  Then inside the function, loop through and copy each value over, and once you reach the index copy in the passed value.

Comment: We are not here to do you're homework.  What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: For my insert method I keep getting the error:  cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Data. I am trying to make a new array which is one size bigger and copy all contents from the "values" array into the "temp array" and then free the memory from values and make it point to tempArray

Comment: One among other thing I can tell about your edited answer, is that your running of the bounds of the `values` array: `for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)` should be `for(int i = 0; i < count-1; i++)`, as you incremented count by one just before. For the rest, it seems that you cannot instantiate a `Data` object because it is declared as abstract, and thus `new Data[count];` should be `new IntegerData[count];`. As told in the message: an abstract class cannot be instantiated, it has to be subclassed to be used... Keep searching ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C++ I would suggest using a vector instead:

```
std::vector<Data *> vect;
...
void insert(Data * other){
    vect.push_back(other);
}
```

Otherwise in C, the function could behave like this :

(Assuming that the way you allocated the `values` array in the first place does not allow dynamic resize...)

- Create a new temporary array `values_tmp` of size (count++)
- Then use [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) to copy the previous data into the new array
- Store the value: `values_tmp[count] = other;` at the end.
- Free the memory for `values`
- Erase `values` with new array: `values = values_tmp;`

Comment: We have to use all code from scratch, and since it's my first time using c++, we haven't learned vectors yet so I am not allowed to use them.

Comment: Added a lead for C: you have to use a temporary array with a size of `count+1`... Assuming that the way you allocated the `values` array in the first place does not allow dynamic resize...

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of your values array is not obvious from the code sample you provided, however, I'll try to give you some advice:

If you *have* to use an array here (and no stl containers), then you should probably initialize it to some moderately sized value, say 128. Keep track of this number, but also keep track of the number of items in it (int count).

When your array gets full you will have to resize. Create a new array of size 256 (which is double the size of the original), copy over elements from the old array, and then delete your old array.

In this way you are resizing at a logarithmic rate, so insertion time can be amortized.

(yes, this is taken from what the stl vector does... if we can't use it, why not imitate it?)

Comment: This is a great Idea but the main focus of this project is memory management. She wants me to dynamically allocate an array to a new size every time I want to insert a new IntegerData and this I don't know how to do.

Comment: @user2510809 Okay, are you familiar with the 'new' operator? This is what is used to dynamically allocate your memory.

Comment: Yes I am, but when I use it in the insert Method it wont compile. I am experienced with Java but this is my first time using c++

Answer (score 0):

This definitely might not be the most efficient way, but you can just create a new array with the new incremented size, loop through and copy each element over 1 by 1 until you reach the insertion index, then copy the inserted element in, then continue copying the rest in and return the new array.

```
IntegerData* insert(Data *other, int index)
{
  IntegerData *newArray = new IntegerData[count +1];
  int offset = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<count+1;i++)
  {
    if (i == index)
    {
      newArray[i] = other;
      offset = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      newArray[i] = oldArray[i-offset];
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```